# DTC Timeout when trying to update oracle table through link that contains a text index

Tags: sql-server, oracle, full-text-search, msdtc

## Problem

Given is a SQL Server connected to an ORACLE Instance as a Linked Server. It’s using the Oracle Client OLEDB Provider. When doing an update in a transaction on a table having a CTXSYS.CONTEXT Text Index the DTC Connection aborts after approx. 10 Min with `Error: 8522, Severity: 18, State: 1` on the commit. As soon you remove the CONTEXT index it works again.

Is this a bug in OraOLEDB or can we do something to fix this issue, while keeping the indexes?

### Setup

#### On ORACLE

We use an ORACLE 11g 11.2.0.2.0

Create this table for this test.

```
CREATE TABLE docs (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR2(200));
INSERT INTO docs VALUES(1, '<HTML>California is a state in the US.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES(2, '<HTML>Paris is a city in France.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES(3, '<HTML>France is in Europe.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES(4, '<HTML>Los Angeles is a city in California.</HTML>');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES(5, '<HTML>Mexico City is big.</HTML>');
COMMIT;
CREATE INDEX idx_docs ON docs(text)
    INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS
    ('FILTER CTXSYS.NULL_FILTER SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.HTML_SECTION_GROUP');
```

#### On MSSQL

We use a SQL Server 2012 Express and Developer Edition both produce the same error. 
Setup a linked server to above Oracle Server with Oracle Provider for OLE DB (OraOLEDB)  Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production.

### Reproduce

#### Working Update

This updates work:

```
set xact_abort off;
update DBLINK..REMOTE_USER.DOCS set text='<HTML>Mexico City is massive.</HTML>' where id = 5;

(1 row(s) affected)
```

This Update Statement produces the error, after the DTC seems to run in a timeout.

```
set xact_abort on;
begin transaction t1
update DBLINK..REMOTE_USER.DOCS set text='<HTML>Mexico City is huge.</HTML>' where id = 5;
commit transaction t1;

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 8522, Level 18, State 1, Line 4
Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.
```

#### Trace

This the end of the trace of a successful update:
[image: successful update trace]

This is the end of the trace of the update that runs into the timeout:
[image: broken update trace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out (after an Oracle SR) this was an already known problem we needed to patch the Oracle Server -> `ORACLE 11G 11.2.0.2 PATCH 27 BUG FOR WINDOWS` helps.